# Drawing on canvas and refreshing image

Tags: android, canvas

Hello and sorry for my bad English.
On my application, onDraw() method draws 10x10 field with lines using canvas.
Then, in other method I want some cells to be painted in yellow for example.

The code is:

```
    Paint ship = new Paint();
    ship.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ship_color));
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Rect r = new Rect(x*(rebro_piece),y*rebro_piece, x*(rebro_piece+1), y*(rebro_piece+1));
    canvas.drawRect(r, ship);
```

but nothing happens. What shall I do?

**UPD**: am I right, that Canvas only draws within onDraw() method and from nothing else?

Comment: you have to call invalidate to schedule a new redraw

Comment: I've added invalidate(r), and still nothing happens.

Comment: Canvas canvas = new
Canvas();

you are drawing over an homeless canvas

Comment: And how I can get the existing canvas to draw on it? The problem is that I call this code from another class, which doesn't extend View

Comment: instead your homeles bitmap because I couldn't find your 10x10 bitmap... >>> `Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(10,10,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);` `Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);` here your code

Comment: And where should I put it? onto onDraw() ? or in my method (code in head of topic) ?